# Connect via jdbc to a self signed certificate opensearch server

Tags: jdbc, opensearch

I am trying to connect to a development opensearch server. The server has a self signed certificate.

Following the documentation I am trying to connect with this url:

`jdbc:opensearch://https://dev01.sandbox.corp:9200/?hostnameVerification=false`

But that gives me this error:

```
Connection error javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

How can I make this connection working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding **trustSelfSigned=true** param did the trick.

So the Url will look like this:

```
jdbc:opensearch://https://dev01.sandbox.corp:9200/?hostnameVerification=false&trustSelfSigned=true
```